# Audio stuttering

Tags: audio

Any audio played through Elementary is stuttering. It is universal, it stutters through Youtube, VLC etc and whether headphones are plugged in or not.

It will stutter for about a second and then not stutter for a minute or so.  Sometimes the gap is longer, sometimes it is shorter.  This is the only distribution that I've experienced this with.

Lenovo G45-50 8Gigs RAM, 1THDD, Quad Core AMD A6 w/ Radeon R4 Graphics.

Comment: I give some shutters when trasfer some gb from internal HD to external HD so I think is this the problem for me, but in other case not have any problems. What audio card you have? You can share the lsmod for check what loaded?

Comment: I can't post the whole lsmod but I hope this concerns the sound. snd                    86016  22 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device

Comment: You can write your audio device name? With this I can't found any informations about your audio card.. Thanks!

Comment: is your problem the same as mine? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5mFzw80mIk